# how to check docker containers and images inside aks nodes

Tags: docker, azure-aks, containerd

how to check running docker containers and images for the deployed pods inside aks nodes?

I have deployed company pods and services inside the azure aks cluster.

Need to login as a root user inside containers running inside nodes of managed aks cluster. Those containers are of rabbitmq pods deployed with bitnami helm chart.

I was able to login into worker nodes by following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-access, but couldn't find the docker package running/installed inside them.

They do have containerd://1.4.9+azure as the CONTAINER-RUNTIME.
Tried below commands of 'containerd' inside those nodes, but nothing came, empty response, no running containers or downloaded images.

```
ctr  container ls
ctr images ls
```

So how to check running docker containers and images for the deployed pods inside aks nodes?

Comment: When you say "check", what (programming-related) action are you trying to perform?  Particularly on managed Kubernetes clusters like AKS you usually can't directly log on to a node and the containers aren't running using Docker _per se_.

Comment: Agree, docker service is not running inside. wanted do some stuff by login as root user inside docker container associated with the pod. Just like we do it in  bare metal or minikube.    minikube ssh "docker container exec -it -u 0 <Container ID> /bin/bash"

Comment: There's a `kubectl exec` command which is probably what you're looking for.  But unless I'm actively debugging something, it's very rare to need to use this.  Consider that there are probably multiple replicas of each pod, and in some cases they can be automatically deleted and recreated (on upgrades, if the cluster autoscaler deletes a node) and anything you do via `kubectl exec` will be inconsistent between replicas and can get deleted without warning.

Comment: with this helm chart 'rabbitmq-6.8.3', we are not able to login as root user inside those pods using kubectl exec. I have to install python software inside that pod using 'apt install python' for doing some stuff with 'rabbitmqadmin' utility inside rabbitmq.

Comment: No, you really don't want to do that.  The pods can get deleted and recreated outside your control and those manual changes will get lost.  If you need additional software included in the container then building a custom Dockerfile is a better approach.

Comment: On the specific topic of [`rabbitmqadmin`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) it talks to an HTTP endpoint so there's no particular reason it needs to run in the same pod.  You should be able to `kubectl port-forward` a port to one of the StatefulSet pods and run `rabbitmqadmin` from your local system.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the info. Just out of curiosity, I wanted to see running containers and images inside worker nodes of the aks cluster. Can we check it somehow? and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the below commands to check running containers inside worker nodes of managed k8s clusters at least in the case of aks clusters.

Here's the reference link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/

use below commands

```
sudo crictl --help
sudo crictl ps
sudo crictl images
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `nerdctl` instead. Here are the steps work for me..

1. Create a debug pod to access the aks node

```
kubectl debug node/<nodeName> -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0
```

2. You can interact with the node session by running below command:

```
chroot /host
```

3. Install `nerdctl` tool:

```
wget https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/releases/download/v0.20.0/nerdctl-0.20.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar zxvf nerdctl-0.20.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin/
alias n=nerdctl
```

4. Check the containers  in the AKS node

```
nerdctl --namespace k8s.io ps -a
```

> Reference:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/crictl/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-access

https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl#whale-nerdctl-load

Comment: I already had your first and second commands, but still thanks for sharing. Downloading and extracting the download seem to work fine, but nerdctl gives me "nerdctl: Exec format error", any clue?

Comment: Seems like it is a format issue. You can refer to [this official doc](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl#basic-usage) for the basic usage. Maybe you can double check what os your node is actually running (`cat /etc/*release*`) and make sure the right package you are downloaded (from [the site](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/releases))